Tendency tones in writing melody
Ever since my last topic, I have written a few chorals and string quartet pieces.
But something is really questionable for me:
That if I already have (for example a third or seventh) in another voice (alto for example), and if the melody (soprano) is moving toward the seventh, should I give the alto another degree?
Or just because it's in a faster time value (quarter or sixteenth notes) it doesn't sound harsh.

Specially when i have arpeggios playing by the viola it seems like it's necessary to have at least the fundamental tone and the third

Try it out. If you like it, keep it. Otherwise don’t do it that way.

This is so context-dependent that it's hard to answer.  In general, only one voice should carry these tones.  But if a voice sounds a tendency tone and then leaves it in an arpeggio, it's much more nuanced.  Give us a bar or two to analyze
